# Sorting results based on score and weight using MongoDB and Springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, sorting

New to Spring boot with Mongo.

I have a current requirement of searching users and listing them based on matching parameters by sorting them based on text index score.

Document is annotated with @TextIndexed along with weight for different parameters. Below is the service function i used to search the user based on different parameters.

```
public SearchResult<UserWithMatchingParams> searchAdvisors(List<String> universities, List<String> professions, List<String> courses, List<String> activities, Double desiredGPA, Integer pageNo, Integer limit){
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("currentRole").is("advisor")
                                .and("isActive").is(true)
                                .and("isOnboarded").is(true)
                                .and("isPublic").is(true);
        List<Criteria> orCriteria = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
        String [] matchingParams = new String[]{};
        if(!universities.isEmpty()){
            orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("advisorProfile.universityName").in(universities));
            matchingParams = mergeArrayOfStrings(matchingParams, universities.toArray(String[]::new));
        }
        if(!professions.isEmpty()){
            orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("advisorProfile.targetProfession").in(professions));
            matchingParams = mergeArrayOfStrings(matchingParams, professions.toArray(String[]::new));
        }
        if(!courses.isEmpty()){
            matchingParams = mergeArrayOfStrings(matchingParams, courses.toArray(String[]::new));
            orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("advisorProfile.advisorCourses.courseName").in(courses));
        }
        if(!activities.isEmpty()){
            matchingParams = mergeArrayOfStrings(matchingParams, activities.toArray(String[]::new));
            orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("advisorProfile.advisorActivities.activityName").in(activities));
        }
        if(desiredGPA!=null){
            orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("advisorProfile.highSchoolGpa").gte(desiredGPA));
        }
        if (!orCriteria.isEmpty()) {
            criteria.orOperator(orCriteria.toArray(new Criteria[orCriteria.size()]));
        }
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        if(matchingParams.length!=0){
            TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(matchingParams);
            query.addCriteria(textCriteria);
            query = query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "score").and(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "advisorProfile.advisorReviewSummary.averageRating")));
        }
        else{
            query = query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt"));
        }
        long total = mongoTemplate.count(query, User.class);
        int skip = (pageNo - 1) * limit;
        query.skip(skip).limit(limit);
        List<User> matchingAdvisors = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(User.class));
        List<UserWithMatchingParams> updatedAdvisors = setMatchingParameterDescriptionForAdvisors(matchingAdvisors, universities, professions, courses, activities, desiredGPA);
        return new SearchResult<UserWithMatchingParams>(updatedAdvisors, total, pageNo, limit);
    }
```

In the AdvisorProfile Document courseName and ActivityName are marked with weight of 15 and universityName is marked with weight of 10. But in search result users with matching university is prioritised first and not the user with matching course. How can i modify the search result priority.

Using Mongo Atlas for database and Spring 2.7.10 with Java 11.

Any suggestions?